# How to iterate over two Maps in Apex?

Tags: apex

In salesforce Apex, I have a below String and facing issues how we can iterate over two maps at a time ?? Can somebody please guide me ... how we can do this ?

```
String values = 'Auth Group:true,HR Group:false';
```

Auth Group:true,HR Group:false

I have two Maps

```
// Map of GroupId and GroupName
Map<Id, String> mapGrpIdAndName = new Map<Id, String>();
mapGrpIdAndName.put('Auth Group','111');
mapGrpIdAndName.put('HR Group','222');

// Map of GroupName and Indicator
Map<String, String> mapGrpNameAndIndicator = new Map<String, String>();
mapGrpNameAndIndicator.put('Auth Group','false');
mapGrpNameAndIndicator.put('HR Group','true');

Assume I am in for loop of case already

for(payment_2__c mysi2 : newSI2){

    Boolean f_indicator = // True or False ==> This value is dynamic........

    if(caseMap.get(mysi2.Case__c).RecordType.DeveloperName != 'ELC_DraftCase'){

        if(caseMap.get(mysi2.Case__c).OwnerId != mysi2.OwnerId){

            if(caseMap.get(mysi2.Case__c).RecordType.DeveloperName == 'AAA_HR'){

                for(Id grpId : mapGrpIdAndName.keySet()){

                    //// HERE I need to check dynamicallt if value of 
                    /// if f_indicator == false and Auth Group == false, then only give apex sharing
                    // How to iterate over two map at a time ???????
                    ////

                    ELC_Service_Information_2__Share gsiShare2 = new ELC_Service_Information_2__Share();
                    gsiShare2.ParentId = mysi2.Id;
                    gsiShare2.RowCause = 'Manual';
                    gsiShare2.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
                    gsiShare2.UserOrGroupId = grpId;
                    si_2ShareList.add(gsiShare2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this compile? Your first Map (mapGrpIdAndName) is instantiated to store an Id and a String; however, you are storing two Strings in it.

Also, if you are looping through the cases already, you don't need to be retrieving the values from caseMap.

It's difficult to understand why you are creating a map only to store two true/false values. I guess you're omitting the real code so we don't use it.

This is how you can do it without looping through the second map:

```
for(Id grpId : mapGrpIdAndName.keySet()){
     if(f_indicator == false && mapGrpNameAndIndicator.get(mapGrpIdAndName.get(grpId)) == 'false'){
         //do whatever 
     }
}
```

Since Group is an sObject, you can use something like this instead:

```
Map<Id, Group> mpGroups = new Map<Id, Group>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Group]);
for(Id grpId : mpGroups.keySet()){
     if(f_indicator == false && mpGroups.get(grpId).Indicator__c == 'false'){
          //do whatever 
     }
}
```

Or:

```
Map<Id, Group> mpGroups = new Map<Id, Group>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Group]);
for(Group grp : mpGroups.values()){
     if(f_indicator == false && grp.Indicator__c == 'false'){
         //do whatever 
     }
}
```